# currently having trouble with lists,strings and integers

Tags: python

i'm trying to challenge myself by coding a version of the card game 21, but i'm having trouble with the strings and integers. my counter also doesn't work and that is beyond me

I've tried defining everything as an integer

## define

```
cardnum1 = " "
cardnum2 = " "

print("the dealer shuffles the cards and deals the first hand")
import random
list = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]
#1st card
card1 = random.choice(list)
print("your first card is ",card1)
#numbers
if card1 == ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]:
    card1=int(cardnum1) 
   

elif card1 == "Jack":
    cardnum1=int(10)


elif card1 == "Queen":
    cardnum1=int(10)


elif card1 == "King":
    cardnum1=int(10)
   

elif card1 == "Ace":
    cardnum1=input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?")
    



card2 = random.choice(list)
print("your second card is ",card2)

#numbers 1 - 10
if card2 == ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]:
    card1=int(cardnum1)
  
#special cards
elif card2 == "Jack":
    cardnum2=int(10)
    

elif card2 == "Queen":
    cardnum2=int(10)
   

elif card2 == "King":
    cardnum2=int(10)
    

elif card2 == "Ace":
    cardnum2=input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?")
 

print ("your cards combined are ",cardnum1 + cardnum2)
```

i'm trying to randomly get 2 cards and the have the program tell me how far i am from 21 and if i've bust or not.
cardnum1 and cardnum2 don't seem to properly add.

i get the error message :

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: You should probably use a dict to correlate cards to numbers and list is a reserved word. Use cards instead so you don’t replace the word list.

Comment: The way you check if a number is in a list is incorrect. You're checking if `card1` equals an entire list. Should be `if card1 in yourlist`. Also you're setting the wrong variable in both of those if conditions. They should be swapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error mentioned is due to the fact that in some circustances one of those variable is a string and the other is an integer.

Actually you have several wrong things:

1. `list` is a built-in in python, do not use the word `list` as a variable.
2. `if card1 == ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]` is wrong. To check if a variable is in a list, do: `if card1 in ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]`. Note the `in` instead of the `==`.
3. `card1=int(cardnum1)` does not make sense if `cardnum1` is `" "`. You probably have them switched: `cardnum1 = int(card1)`.
4. `cardnum1=int(10)` is not wrong, but 10 is already an integer. the `int()` is redundant, totally not needed.
5. `cardnum2=input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?")` I suppose here you expect the user to type 1 or 11. If you are using python3, `input` always return a  string, so you must convert it to an integer: `cardnum2=int(input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?"))`. If you are using python2 instead is fine.

Comment: Great and detailed answer

Comment: thanks, i'm relatively new to all this so thanks for telling me about this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dict to assign numbers to a card and you can choose 2 cards using `random.choices`

```
import random

cards = {
    1: "Ace",
    2: "2",
    3: "3",
    4: "4",
    5: "5",
    6: "6",
    7: "7",
    8: "8",
    9: "9",
    10: "10",
    11: "Jack",
    12: "Queen",
    13: "King"
}

print("the dealer shuffles the cards and deals the first hand")

card_num1, card_num2 = random.choices(list(cards), k=2)
card1, card2 = cards[card_num1], cards[card_num2]

print("your first card is ",card1)

print("your second card is ",card2)
```

And to put them all into one sentence easily you can use `.format()` or f-strings in Python 3.6+.

```
print(f"Your cards combined are {card1} {card2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in my comment, you were incorrectly checking for list inclusion and you were setting the wrong variables in the if statements. Here's your code fixed:

```
import random
cardnum1 = " "
cardnum2 = " "

print("the dealer shuffles the cards and deals the first hand")
list = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
        "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
# 1st card
card1 = random.choice(list)
print("your first card is ", card1)

# numbers
if card1 in ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]:
    cardnum1 = int(card1)


elif card1 == "Jack":
    cardnum1 = int(10)


elif card1 == "Queen":
    cardnum1 = int(10)


elif card1 == "King":
    cardnum1 = int(10)


elif card1 == "Ace":
    cardnum1 = input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?")


card2 = random.choice(list)
print("your second card is ", card2)

# numbers 1 - 10
if card2 in ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]:
    cardnum2 = int(card2)

# special cards
elif card2 == "Jack":
    cardnum2 = int(10)


elif card2 == "Queen":
    cardnum2 = int(10)


elif card2 == "King":
    cardnum2 = int(10)


elif card2 == "Ace":
    cardnum2 = input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?")

print("your cards combined are ", cardnum1 + cardnum2)
```

Answer (score 0):

While others have given working versions of your program, and pointed out the issues with your version, let me offer a simple alternative of how you could do it:

```
import random

deck = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

card1 = random.choice(deck)
card2 = random.choice(deck)

def card_value(card):
    if card == 'Ace':
        chosen_value = input("do you want your Ace to be a 1 or a 11?")
        return int(chosen_value)
    elif card in ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']:
        return 10
    else:
        # Return the integer as it is
        return card

print("Your first card is", card1)
print("Your first card is", card2)

print("Your cards combined are ", card_value(card1) + card_value(card2))
```

The only major difference between this version and yours is that I use a `card_value` helper method to derive the value of the card as an integer. If the card value is already an integer, it just returns as it is.

***P.S:***

Welcome to the world of programming, and it's super cool that you are trying to challenge yourself this early. Don't worry about the downvotes to your question; It happens. But you can avoid it by taking a methodical approach to your problem:

- First write down an algorithm in plain english or pseudocode
- Code and test each stage of the algorithm
- Write tests that check expected output with actual output

In the beginning, you may also find it beneficial to invest time and learn how to think like a programmer, than dig deep into any one language. See these links to know what I mean:

- https://zapier.com/blog/think-like-a-programmer/
- [https://www.amazon.com/Think-Like-Programmer-Introduction-Creative/dp/1593274246](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593274246)
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-think-like-a-programmer-lessons-in-problem-solving-d1d8bf1de7d2